# Creating User Profile Data Connection in InfoPath 2013 (Office 365)

Tags: 2013, infopath, office-365

I'm trying to create a data connection for the user profile in InfoPath 2013 but am receiving this error:

> The data source file is accessed through a redirection from a
>   different domain, which is not allowed. If you want to use this data
>   source file, copy it to a location within your security domain. Access
>   is denied.

What should I do?

Comment: Is the given solution works for you?

Comment: No, it didn't work. Still getting the same error. Is there a way I can see what groups that call can see?

Comment: It is showing that you are accessing the INFOPATH FORM from outside the SharePoint domain. Or your firewall blocks the port where it is hosted. Nothing to do with the groups

Comment: But I have my firewall turned off. Is there anything else I should turn off?

Comment: Can you access the site outside the domain? as it is showing that you are using the form available in different domain. So it is not allowing you to access the form.

Comment: Is it possible to chat?

Answer (score 0):

> The feature should be enabled in SharePoint Online. I suggest you
>   troubleshoot the issue with the following steps:
>
> 1. Have you ever opened two or more SharePoint sites at the same time when you test the InfoPath form? If so, please close all the sites,
>      clear the browser cache, and test it again.
> 2. Close the local firewall, and test the issue.
> 3. If the computer is a domain-joined computer, please login the computer with a non-domain user, and perform a test.
>
> If all the above steps fail, please create a new SharePoint List from
>   InfoPath 2010, publish it, and test the preview mode before you close
>   the InfoPath.